# Rails query select as a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Trying to do a select with a hash and postgresql schemas.

This is only half the line and its huge as you can see.

```
Content::Resource.joins(:language, :_resource_api_version).select("i18n.language.language_code,i18n.language.unicode, i18n.language.english, i18n.language.direction")
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
.select("i18n.language": [:language_code, :unicode, :english, :direction])
```

Is that possible?

Then I want to implement the same thing with a 'where' statement:

```
.where("content.resource_api_version.v2_is_enabled = 't' AND content.resource.is_available = 't'")
```

Comment: Rails 4.1.1 and my database is huge to describe it!

Comment: The problem is that my lines of queries are far too long and I am looking for advice on making it shorting or a more hash conventional way rather than writing long strings of queries. so instead of writing  `.select("i18n.language.language_code,i18n.language.unicode ...` I am looking for advice for a shorter, better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a map:

```
select([:language_code, :unicode, :english, :direction].map{ |term| "i18n.language.#{term}" }.join(', '))
```

Comment: How about the `where` same thing?

Comment: I need more detail about the where, I dont know what you want to do

Comment: I want to do the hash conditions

Comment: What if I don't want to do select on just "i18n.language" but on that and other things?